# Why do I need to double click on button for JQuery to render partial view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, load, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Wondering why it doesn't load on one click, but on two.................................................................?

```
<input id="btnPaymentAdd" type="button" value="Add Payment Info" />
</p>
<div id="paymentSection"></div>
<br />    

....

$("#btnPaymentAdd").click(function () {
    $("#paymentSection").load('/Donation/AddPaymentInfo');
    $("#paymentSection").show('slow');
});

....

public ActionResult AddPaymentInfo()
{

    var vModel = new PaymentViewModel();
    vModel.Payment = new Payments();
    vModel.PaymentType = new WCCDentalApp.Models.PaymentType();

    ViewBag.PaymentTypes = new SelectList(dbEntities.PaymentTypes.OrderBy(pt => pt.PaymentTypeID),
    "PaymentTypeID", "PaymentType1", vModel.Payment.PaymentTypeID);

    return PartialView("PaymentPView", vModel);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind your `.show()` function after the page loads...

```
$("#btnPaymentAdd").click(function(){
    $("#paymentSection").load('/Donation/AddPaymentInfo', function(){
         $(this).show('slow');
    });
});
```

or you can use `.get()`, like this:

```
$("#btnPaymentAdd").click(function(){
    $.get('/Donation/AddPaymentInfo', function(data){
         $("#paymentSection").html(data).show('slow');
    });
});
```

Otherwise, the way you have it will just do the `.show()` without waiting for the page to load, will make you think like clicking it twice works.